# Convert vector of matrix (opencv) into c++ array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a vector Io of four matrices (Io has m columns and n rows) that I want to create a big array 'result' (c++ array, not a 1D opencv vector, length of 'result' should be 4*m*n) with all the matrices reshaped to 1D with their entities concatenated back to back to each other.

So far this is what I did. But I feel it's a bit lengthy. It would be nice to have alternative solution that looks better.

```
Mat Iotem1 = Io[0].reshape(0, 1); vector<float> vec1; Iotem1.copyTo(vec1);
Mat Iotem2 = Io[1].reshape(0, 1); vector<float> vec2; Iotem2.copyTo(vec2);
Mat Iotem3 = Io[2].reshape(0, 1); vector<float> vec3; Iotem3.copyTo(vec3);
Mat Iotem4 = Io[3].reshape(0, 1); vector<float> vec4; Iotem3.copyTo(vec4); 
float * result = new float[4*data_SIZE];
vec1.insert(vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), vec2.end());
vec1.insert(vec1.end(), vec3.begin(), vec3.end());
vec1.insert(vec1.end(), vec4.begin(), vec4.end());
memcpy(result, &vec1[0], sizeof(int) * vec1.size());
```

Comment: You can do it simply and silently. What problems you faced?

Comment: Hi Tiib, I edited my questions. Thanks

Comment: Erase these "float* Iotem#_array"s, these are unused and also put everything into that vec1 in cycle.